# Source for story about a murdering son-in-law whose family was swallowed alive

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, reward-punishment, murder

I stumbled upon a really random story in the middle of a *sefer* on the [*Azharos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azharot) of [**Rav Shlomo ibn Gabirol**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_ibn_Gabirol). The author says he heard it from his father. Since he was discussing the prohibition of murder, he decided to relate the story.

It's a long story which you can [read here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=39221#p=278&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=), but a quick summary is in the times of the *Rishonim* there was a wealthy *talmid chochom* who saw in a dream that his daughter will marry a murderer. He tried very hard to avoid it, but right after his daughter got married the new son-in-law murdered an old man and stole his money, in order to support his family. The wealthy *talmid chochom* saw in a dream that his new son-in-law had in fact murdered, and confronted him. He demanded the son-in-law go to the grave of the deceased and and to report what he hears. He heard a Heavenly voice announce that this murderer will be punished in forty years from the murder. The wealthy *talmid chochom* recorded the date of the murder, plus forty years, in a book. This son-in-law carried on his life and had children and grandchildren. On the destined night recorded in the book, the whole house was swallowed up alive, with all the family members inside.

Does this story appear anywhere else/earlier in print? It's way too detailed to be true...it sounds more like a way of scaring children from murdering.

Comment: "It's way too detailed to be true." True stories have details also.

Comment: The author was a prominent Tunisian rabbi https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F

Comment: @wfb I think that's a different Shaul HaKohen. My impression is this one lived in the 16th century ish

Comment: @robev nope, one and the same. See R. Mazuz's chapter about him in Migedolei Yisrael vol. 1